# How to set Alarm Every Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nscalendar

i want set alarm every day please help me
i am so confused about it from many days. 
i am using this code

```
-(void)localNotificationWithData:(NSDate *)firDate timeinterval:(int)interval{

NSCalendar *calender = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDate *pickerDate = firDate;
NSLog(@"%@",pickerDate);

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calender components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit)fromDate:pickerDate];
/*... here we get Weekdays throug loop....*/
int rand = arc4random()%100;
NSLog(@"%d",rand);
for (int i=0; i<[strMarkList length]; i++) {
    NSString *getselectedCell=[strMarkList substringWithRange:(NSRange){i,1}];
    NSLog(@"%i",[getselectedCell intValue]);
    if ([getselectedCell intValue]== 0) {
        [dateComponents setDay:1];
        [dateComponents setWeekday:1];
        NSDate *itemDate = [calender dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
        [self repeatWeekDayInterval:itemDate rand:rand];
    }else if ([getselectedCell intValue]== 1) {
        [dateComponents setDay:2];
        [dateComponents setWeekday:2];
        NSDate *itemDate = [calender dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
        [self repeatWeekDayInterval:itemDate rand:rand];
    }else if ([getselectedCell intValue]== 2) {
        [dateComponents setDay:3];
        [dateComponents setWeekday:3];
        localNofi.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitWeekday+7;
        NSDate *itemDate = [calender dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
        [self repeatWeekDayInterval:itemDate rand:rand];
    }else if ([getselectedCell intValue]== 3) {
        [dateComponents setDay:4];
        [dateComponents setWeekday:4];
        NSDate *itemDate = [calender dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
        [self repeatWeekDayInterval:itemDate rand:rand];
    }else if ([getselectedCell intValue]== 4) {
        [dateComponents setDay:5];
        [dateComponents setWeekday:5];
        NSDate *itemDate = [calender dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
        [self repeatWeekDayInterval:itemDate rand:rand];
    }else if ([getselectedCell intValue]== 5) {
        [dateComponents setDay:6];
        [dateComponents setWeekday:6];
        NSDate *itemDate = [calender dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
        [self repeatWeekDayInterval:itemDate rand:rand];
    }else if ([getselectedCell intValue]== 6) {
        [dateComponents setDay:7];
        [dateComponents setWeekday:7];
        NSDate *itemDate = [calender dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
        [self repeatWeekDayInterval:itemDate rand:rand];
    }
}
/*.....end.....*/


// NOW LOCALNOTIFICATION FIRE
```

}

```
 -(void)repeatWeekDayInterval:(NSDate *)itemDate rand:(int)rand{
if (localNofi == nil)
    return;
localNofi.fireDate = itemDate;
NSLog(@"%@",itemDate);
localNofi.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNofi.alertBody = @"Time To Weak Up";
localNofi.alertAction = @"View";
localNofi.soundName = @"alarm-clock-bell.caf";
localNofi.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
localNofi.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

identifiLclNoti = rand;
NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",identifiLclNoti] forKey:@"identifyKey"];
localNofi.userInfo = infoDict;
NSLog(@"%@",localNofi);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNofi];
```

}

please tell me what is wrong or i stuck in this problem for many day i search many time on google but can't find any good way please do something for me 
please please help me......thanks

Answer (score 1):

i just saw your schedule notification code, its fine and working. Just you need to change the below to pop up local notification every week.

```
localNofi.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
```

I have tested it on iOS 6.0 simulator, got the required results, let me know if it didn't worked you.

Comment: ok i added but one more problem today day is wednesday ok now when i select monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday ok then alarm is started from wednesday weddesday wednesday and then go next but not add monday and tuesday bec today is wednesday that is my problem how ican fix it.

Comment: i think it has only one solution add schedule notif only for that programattically  with weekday repeat.. i don't think just with one repeatInterval & one notif that can be achieved..

Comment: look in my tableviewcell i set monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday if all selected then above code is run properly when i get all all alarm then in which monday and tuesday is convert wednesday meadn three alarm is become wednesday one is today alarm wednesday and previous 2 today mean monday and tuesday also convert wednesday

Comment: when i selected all cell then get all alarm and print this is result and tell me this is right answer
http://pastie.org/7299962
check this and tell me